# Use $translate on items that are from Database

Tags: angularjs, localization

I have a problem that I cannot get around. The app is in Angular JS and is using `pascalprecht.translate`. I have a list of items that are called on from the database in json form. The json has data in two languages, Arabic and English.

How can I make the items in the select box change language when the language is changed via `$translate.use()` in the applicable/current controller. How can I implement this?

***What have I tried:***

- Using Static fields like all the other translations ( this will make the app work but seems like a dirty way to get things done
- Creating a RootScope function that changes the key to `en` or `ar` but I cannot figure how how to trigger that function on **all** the select elements on the given page. I cant think of `$watch` but how can I trigger it to work on all select?

The data is in the following format:

```
[
    {en:"Data in En 1", ar: "Data in Ar 1"},
    {en:"Data in En 2", ar: "Data in Ar 2"},
    {en:"Data in En 3", ar: "Data in Ar 3"},
    ...
]
```

Regards!

Comment: How do you identify the translation, by a key? Like in `$translate`? I mean, `"DATA_TRANLATION_KEY": {en:"Data in En 1", ar: "Data in Ar 1"},`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter to handle the data translation according to your translation format like:

```
<span>{{ { "en":"Data in En 1", "ar": "Data in Ar 1"} | translateData }}</span>
```

The following code is a simple implementation of a filter that behaves like this, so that you can modify it to fit properly within your code.

```
;(function () {

    angular.module('app.filters', ['ngTranslate'])
        .filter('translateData', TranslateData);

    function TranslateData($translate) {

        return function TranslateDataFilter(data) {

            if (!angular.isObject(data)) { // don't handle it if it's not an obj
                return data;
            }

            var lang = $translate.use(); // get current app language

            return data[lang]; // return the prop value named by the `lang`
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out!